# Convert JSON date format

Tags: java, json, date, parsing

I'm receiving a JSON object with date value like this:

```
{"PostingDate":"\/Date(1325134800000-0500)\/"}
```

And I want to parse it in Java code to `Date` or getting it as a `String`.

I want to know what is the easy way of doing it.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not "JSON date format" -- the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) does not include a date format.

Comment: By the way, this is a terrible way to communicate a date-time value. See the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for practical, unambiguous, and easy-to-parse formats for date-time values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it the first number (`1325134800000`) is the number of milliseconds since epoch, and `-0500` is the time zone. This appears to be the case given the sample code below, which seems to do what you want.

The following code parses the JSON input using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), which I recommend if you don't have a JSON parsing library of choice yet. It lacks error checking etc.

Sample code:

```
public final class Foo
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        // What the JSON value must match exactly
        // Not anchored since it will be used with the (misnamed) .matches() method
        final Pattern pattern
            = Pattern.compile("\\\\/Date\\((\\d+)(-\\d+)?\\)\\\\/");

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Parse JSON...
        final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(
            "{\"PostingDate\": \"\\/Date(1325134800000-0500)\\/\"}");

        if (!node.has("PostingDate")) {
            System.err.println("Bad JSON input!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Get relevant field
        final String dateSpec = node.get("PostingDate").getTextValue();

        // Try and match the input.
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dateSpec);

        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            System.err.println("Bad pattern!"); // Yuck
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // The first group capture the milliseconds, the second one the time zone

        final long millis = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
        String tz = matcher.group(2);
        if (tz.isEmpty()) // It can happen, in which case the default is assumed to be...
            tz = "+0000";

        // Instantiate a date object...    
        final Date date = new Date(millis);

        // And print it using an appropriate date format
        System.out.printf("Date: %s %s\n",
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss").format(date), tz);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 2011/12/29 06:12:00 -0500
```

Comment: This special syntax has been invented by Microsoft to make those Date literals distinguishable from normal strings, but still deliver valid JSON. See http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx

Comment: But the timezone part is a new one, though... looks like someone "improved" MS' hack.

Comment: I'm trying doing what you worte but I get error when calling matcher.group(1) and the attribute matchFound of the matcher says false.. could it be problem with the regex (i have tried more options but no good).. ??!?

Comment: Can you post the string literal you are trying to match? Beware that Java requires that you double backslashes. Also, what is the result of calling `.toString()` on the first JsonNode?

Comment: The string I get from this code: this.getJSONObject().getString("PostingDate") is: "/Date(1325134800000-0500)/"  and this is what been given  to the matcher: pattern.matcher(this.getJSONObject().getString("PostingDate"))

Comment: found it! I just had to call matcher.find(), I guess this is what matcher.matches() in your code does and I skeep it.. :) Thanks!

Comment: Still, this is not normal. According to the link posted by @ammoQ, the format should be _exactly_ `\/Date(xxxxx)\/` (unquoted, and with the added timezone spec in your case). You should not have to use find() here. What does your JSON library return as the string literal? It definitely looks wrong -- and which is why I use Jackson

Comment: I don't recommend Jackson because it relies too much on auto-magically converting beans to JSON. I prefer Jettison instead.

Comment: @smcg I don't use any kind of POJO mapping here. The

Answer (score 0):

Hier is a working parsing method based on the version of fge but improved as

1. it used jode's DateTime with the correct timezone initialized
2. minor change to pattern to accept +0200 too

=>

```
private static final Pattern bingTimePattern = Pattern.compile("\\/Date\\((\\d+)([-+]\\d+)?\\)\\/");

public static DateTime parseBingTime(String timeAsString) throws ParseException {
    Matcher matcher = bingTimePattern.matcher(timeAsString);
    if (!matcher.find())
        throw new ParseException("wrong date time format " + timeAsString, 0);

    final long millis = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
    String tz = matcher.group(2);
    if (tz.isEmpty())
        tz = "+0000";

    return new DateTime(millis, DateTimeZone.forID(tz));
}
```

Comment: Actually you have to compile the pattern like so: "\\\\/Date\\((\\d+)([-+]\\d+)?\\)\\\\/". you have to double escape the first and last \ characters. once for  java string and again for regex. also tz == null if there is no timezone so if statement should be if(tz == null || tz.isEmpty())

Comment: no, it works like expected for me. check for null is good, but better checking for existing group(2) ...

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple JavaScript function using Jquery DatePicker

> ```
>     function JsonToJSDate(jsonDate) {
>         var reg = /-?\d+/;
>         var m = reg.exec(jsonDate);
>         return new Date(parseInt(m[0]));            
>     }
> ```

**$('#Started').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', JsonToJSDate(yourDateVarHere)));**

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing but handling my job.
Extract your object value from JSON and apply substring.
e.g:

```
      String postingDateObjectValue = "\\/Date(1442436473422)\\/";

      String dateStringInMillis = postingDateObjectValue .substring(7,20);
```

now parse millis and use them where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Java >= 8 you can use the [new `java.time` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime).

The input contains:

- a [unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469753/7605325) (`1325134800000`), which is the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`)
- a [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (`-0500`), which is the difference from [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html) (in this case, 5 hours behind UTC)

In the new `java.time` API, there are [lots of different types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) of date/time objects. In this case, we can choose to use a `java.time.Instant` (which represent a count of nanoseconds since unix epoch) or a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` (which represents the `Instant` converted to a date/time in a specific offset).

To parse the `String`, I use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to create a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`. I also use a `java.time.temporal.ChronoField` to specify which fields I'm parsing:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // epoch seconds
    .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
    // milliseconds
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
    // offset
    .appendPattern("xx")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

I also use a regex to extract just the relevant part from the input `String` (although you could also use `substring()` to get it):

```
String s = "/Date(1325134800000-0500)/";

// get just the "1325134800000-0500" part - you can also do s.substring(6, 24)
s = s.replaceAll(".*/Date\\(([\\d\\+\\-]+)\\)/.*", "$1");
```

Then I can parse to the type I want:

```
// parse to Instant
Instant instant = Instant.from(fmt.parse(s));
// parse to OffsetDateTime
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(s, fmt);
```

The `Instant` is equivalent to `2011-12-29T05:00:00Z` (`Instant` is just a point in the timeline, and you can think that's always in UTC).
The `OffsetDateTime` has the same instant, but converted to `-0500` offset, so its value is `2011-12-29T00:00-05:00`. But both `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` represents the same point in time.

---

To convert to `java.util.Date`, use the `Instant`:

```
// convert to java.util.Date
Date date = Date.from(instant);

// if you have an OffsetDateTime, you can do this:
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

That's because the `java.util.Date` [has no timezone/offset information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) and it just represents the count of milliseconds since unix epoch (the same concept of `Instant`), so it can be easily converted from an `Instant`.

---

## Java 6 and 7

For Java 6 and 7, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The difference from Java 8 is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same. So the formatter creation and the parsing code to `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` are the same.

Another difference is that, in Java <= 7, the `java.util.Date` class has no `from()` method. But you can use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class to do the conversion:

```
// convert to java.util.Date
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(instant);

// or from the OffsetDateTime
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(odt.toInstant());
```