# Java method to parse Date as MS JSON date format

Tags: java, json.net

Microsoft uses a datetime format that looks like this: `\/Date(1399017480000-0000)\/`

I would like to write a Java method that converts a Java date to Microsoft's datetime format. Can anyone point to a resource that explains how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `SimpleDateFormat` ?

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700385/convert-json-date-format

Comment: As far as I am concerned `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't perform this kind of conversion.

Comment: oh sorry see link I have posted..

Comment: No. I don't want it as a standard format. I want it as a dot net format.

Comment: That's not a "dot net" format at all, nor is it a Microsoft format. It's one of the many JSON formats.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know this is ancient by now... but can Noda Time parse this kind of strings? My google-fu is failing me.

Comment: @Daniel: No. You could write your own converter that would plug into NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet, but you'd have to parse the millisecond value as an integer etc. (There's no Noda Time pattern format that deals with it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're just talking about `java.util.Date`, it's as simple as:

```
public static String toJson(Date date) {
    return "\\/Date(" + date.getTime() + "-0000)\\/";
}
```

(That's assuming the backslashes should really be part of the string... it's not clear whether you actually want them or not, but you can remove them easily enough.)

Basically the first part of the string is just the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which is the value in a `java.util.Date` as well, as accessed via [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--).

The "0000" bit is a UTC offset, but as a `java.util.Date` has no concept of a time zone or an offset, you can just use 0000 and you'll end up representing the right instant in time. If you were starting with a `java.util.Calendar` value you could convert the offset as well, if you really wanted to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I know Java doesn't have the notion of a TimeZone but do you mean I don't have to care about the timezone when I am posting dates to the ASP.Net server?

Comment: @SandahAung: Java *does* have the notion of a time zone (look at `java.util.TimeZone`; it's just that `java.util.Date` doesn't. As for whether or not you need to worry about time zones - that's very context-sensitive. Does the time zone matter for the data you're posting?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Java's date doesn't. It looks like the server finds it useful to know the client's correct timezone since it can use that information to perform certain tasks such as send alerts at the appropriate time.

Comment: `Date` is very old; Java has much better date-related classes now.  If you want to be aware of timezones, an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) would probably be more suitable.  (Or if not, a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).)

Comment: @gidds: This answer is very old too! But for a time-zone-aware type, I'd suggest `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` - neither of those know about time zones.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I forgot I'd followed a link here :-)  And yes, I'm sure you're right about `ZonedDateTime`.  (I haven't used the new date & time API enough yet.)