# Java JSONParser distinguish type of the object

Tags: java, json, date, serialization, deserialization

I have a `Date` serializer which when deserializing `Date` objects adds timezone, but I noticed that some of the `Date` objects are converted to `String` and instead of long value I get a `String` value of `Date`.

So when I try to:

```
Long dateValue = jsonParser.getLongValue();
Date date = new Date(dateValue);
```

It throws format exception, so when I get `Date` in the shape of **`**String**`**  I need to do

```
String dateString = jsonParser.getText();
```

The value of `dateString` is `"2017-09-06"`.

Is there a way to know what type is **jsonParser** object? Because `instanceof` doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: What's the value of `dateString`?

Comment: It is a string "2017-09-06"

Answer (score 0):

If instanceof doesn't work you can use to convert String into Long this might be work.

```
Long.valueOf(String s).longValue();
```

Comment: This won't help as exception is thrown jsonParser.getLongValue()

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the `String` is `2017-09-06`, that's why you can't get it as a `long`. To get a `Date` from this `String`, you need to use a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String dateString = "2017-09-06";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

The only problem is that a `Date` is not exactly a date (with a defined day/month/year). It has [no format and no timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), it has just the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z` (January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at midnight in **[UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html)**) - also called "unix timestamp", "millis value" and [many other names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469753/7605325).

Using the `SimpleDateFormat` above will create a `Date` with the specified date (September 6<sup>th</sup> 2017). As the time isn't specified, it will default to midnight, and it will also use the JVM default timezone. So this can return different dates (different millis values) depending on the timezone set in the JVM.

If you want to use a specific timezone, just set in the formatter:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

I used `Europe/London`, but you can use any other timezone you want. You can get a list of all available zones (and choose the best for your case) by calling `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To parse this `String`, you can use a `LocalDate`:

```
// get a LocalDate from 2017-09-06
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
```

Then you can convert it to a `Date`. In the code below I'm simulating what `SimpleDateFormat` does: set the time to midnight at the JVM default timezone. In Java 8 you can use `Date.from` method, and in Java 7, the ThreeTen Backport API has the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
// convert to java.util.Date (Java 8)
Date d = Date.from(dt.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
// convert to java.util.Date (Java 7 ThreeTen Backport)
Date d = DateTimeUtils.toDate(dt.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Just reminding that using the default timezone can be tricky, because this [can be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using.

You can specify which timezone you want by using `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")` - changing `Europe/London` to the timezone you want. To get a list of all zones, use `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

---

Not in the scope of the question, but you can also use an API (such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)) to deal with JSON - it has built-in conversions from and to most types, including dates. In the [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson) tag you'll find lots of related questions regarding date manipulation.