# Which date format is this? 1370131200000

Tags: javascript, datetime

> 1370131200000

I was using hichart to plot timeline data. in the example the date field in x axis is like this. But my timestamp values are like 1502582400.

Comment: this is a timestamp , you can check this website for human readable date: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Or just by using `Date(1502582400)` for example returns: "Thu Sep 07 2017 12:06:48 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript Date.now() time format called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461541/what-is-the-javascript-date-now-time-format-called)

Comment: @chiragsatapara actually if you closely see at those number there are extra zeroes in. the rumber :  1370131200000  => Sunday, June 2, 2013 12:00:00 AM .  1502582400 => GMT: Sunday, August 13, 2017 12:00:00 AM. How can a timestamp with less digit can be the time of future date.

Comment: @Madhab452, there are extra zeroes in number because this timestamp also consider the miliseconds

Comment: @chiragsatapara  i just multiplied by 1000 and it worked. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's UNIX time stamp ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

1502582400 is 08/13/2017 @ 12:00am (UTC)

You can find how to convert to other formats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript dates are numbers which specify the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.