# How do I convert local time zone to utc and utc local time zone?

Tags: java, datetime, utc, datetime-conversion

I want to store UTC time in DB (`yyyy-mm-dd` or `dd-mm-yyyy`)

1. I want to convert local time zone to UTC and store it in DB

I tried in different ways but that is not working properly. Below is my code for convert local to UTC

2. get the UTC time from DB and convert to local timezone

Below is my code for both:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TestDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        /*Date de = new Date();
        DateFormat converter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.err.println(converter1.format(de));
        Date der =*/
                localToGMT();
//          System.err.println("0000 : "+converter1.format(der));
        Date d=  new Date("09/10/2017 21:53:17");
        gmttoLocalDate(d);
    }

    public static Date localToGMT() {
//      Date gmt = new Date(sdf.format(date));
        Date gmt = null;
        Date localTime =  new Date();
         //creating DateFormat for converting time from local timezone to GMT
         DateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

         //getting GMT timezone, you can get any timezone e.g. UTC
         converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
         System.out.println("local time : " + localTime);;
         System.out.println("time in GMT : " + converter.format(localTime));

         try {
            gmt =converter.parse((converter.format(localTime)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         /*Date date = new Date("2017/10/10 12:04:28");
         System.err.println(date);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        gmt = sdf.parse(sdf.format(date));*/
        System.err.println("converted to utc :" + gmt);
        return gmt;
    }

    public static Date gmttoLocalDate(Date date) {
        String timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
        Date local = new Date(date.getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone).getOffset(date.getTime()));
        System.err.println("converted to local timezone :" + local);
        return local;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Date` has [no format, nor any timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). Is the database field a date/timestamp or a string/text/varchar type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local to UTC

```
 public static Date localToUTC() {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date gmt = new Date(sdf.format(date));
    return gmt;
    }
```

UTC to local

```
public static Date utctoLocalDate(Date date) {

String timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
Date local = new Date(date.getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone).getOffset(date.getTime()));
return local
```

}

Comment: thank you for your response. return gmt and return local are display like this wed oct 12 12:33:99 ist 2017 but response value want to store in db i want response 2017-10-12 12:54:54

Answer (score 4):

A `java.util.Date` [**has no timezone information**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). It has only a `long` value, which is the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (which is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` or **January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at midnight in UTC**).
This value (number of milliseconds since epoch) has [many names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469753/7605325), I'll just call it **timestamp** for short.

The timestamp is an "absolute" value, it's the same everywhere in the world.
 Example: I've just got the current time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) and the result was `1507722750315` (that's the current number of milliseconds since epoch). This value is the same for everyone in the world. But this same value can **correspond** to a different date/time in each timezone:

- in UTC, it corresponds to `2017-10-11T11:52:30.315Z`
- in São Paulo (Brazil), it's `2017-10-11T08:52:30.315-03:00`
- in London, it's `2017-10-11T12:52:30.315+01:00`
- in Tokyo, it's `2017-10-11T20:52:30.315+09:00`
- in India, it's `2017-10-11T17:22:30.315+05:30`
- in Auckland, it's `2017-10-12T00:52:30.315+13:00` (it's already "tomorrow" there)
- and so on...

So, when you do a method that receives a `java.util.Date` and tries to convert it to another `java.util.Date`, you're not converting anything. The `Date` contains only the timestamp value (the "absolute" value that corresponds to a specific point in time). But the `Date` itself doesn't know anything about timezones, so it's pointless to do such convertion (the timestamp is the same for the whole world, there's no need to convert it).

---

## *"But when I print the date, I see the value in my local time"*

Well, this is explained [in this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). If you `System.out.println` a `Date`, or log it, or look its value in a debugger, you'll see something like:

> Wed Oct 12 12:33:99 IST 2017

But that's because the `toString()` method is being implicity called, and this method converts the timestamp value to the JVM default timezone (so it looks like a "local date/time").

But remember, this `Wed Oct etc` string is **not** the actual value hold by the `Date` object: all it has is the timestamp that corresponds to that date/time displayed. But the date object itself doesn't has any notion of local date/time, nor any timezone related information. What you see is just a **representation** of the timestamp value, in a specific format, for a specific timezone.

---

## What to do then?

If the database field is a **date** type, then the JDBC driver usually handles it, so you just save the `Date` object directly. There's no need to care about formats and timezones, because the `Date` has no format, nor any timezone information.

The problem with date types is that any language/database/vendor/application shows it in a different way. Java's `Date.toString()` converts it to the JVM default timezone, some databases shows in a specific format (dd/mm/yyyy, or yyyy-mm-dd, etc) and converts to whatever timezone configured in the DB, and so on.

But remember that a date itself has no format. It has just a value, the thing is that the same date can be **represented** in different formats. Example: **October 15th 2017** can be represented as `2017-10-15`, `10/15/2017`, `15th Oct 2017`, `15 de Outubro de 2017` (in **pt_BR** (portuguese) locale) and so on. The format (the **representation**) is different, but the `Date` **value** is the same.

So, if you're dealing with `Date` objects, the database field is a date-related type and it returns and saves the `Date` object, just use it directly.

---

If you want to **display** this date, though, (show to an user, or log it), or if the database field is a `String` (or a varchar, or any other text-related type), then it's a completely different matter.

When printing a date (or converting it to a `String`), you can choose the format and the timezone you're converting to, using a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
// a java.util.Date with the same timestamp above (1507722750315)
Date date = new Date(1507722750315L);
// choose a format
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// choose a timezone to convert to
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
// convert to a String
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // 2017-10-11 17:22:30
```

In this case, the output is:

> 2017-10-11 17:22:30

If I change the timezone to another one, the result will be converted to it:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
// convert to a String
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // 2017-10-11 12:52:30
```

Now the result is:

> 2017-10-11 12:52:30

But the `Date` value is still the same: if you call `date.getTime()`, it'll return the timestamp value, which is still `1507722750315`. I just changed the **representation** of this date (the format and the timezone). But the `Date` itself has its value unchanged.

Also note that I used [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `IST` or `CET`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

You can also use the system's default timezone with `TimeZone.getDefault()`, but this [can be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to explicity use a specific one.

---

To get a `Date` from a `String`, don't use the deprecated constructor (`new Date("09/10/2017 21:53:17")`). It's better to use a `SimpleDateFormat` and set the timezone this date refers to.

In the tests I've made, `09/10/2017` is interpreted as "month/day/year", so I'm going to use the same. I'm also considering that the input is in UTC, but you can change it to whatever timezone you need:

```
String s = "09/10/2017 21:53:17";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
// the input is in UTC (change it to the timezone you need)
parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date d = parser.parse(s);
```

The date above will be equivalent to September 10<sup>th</sup> 2017, at 21:53:17 in **UTC**. If the input is in another timezone, just change "UTC" by the corresponding timezone name.

[Check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all possible formats used by `SimpleDateFormat`.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java 6 or 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The newest JDBC drivers already have support to new Java 8 types (check if yours already has). But if you still need to use `java.util.Date`, you can easily convert from/to the new API.

In Java 8, `Date` has the new `from` and `toInstant` methods, to convert from/to the new `java.time.Instant` class:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
```

In ThreeTen Backport, you can use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class to convert from/to `org.threeten.bp.Instant`:

```
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(instant);
Instant instant = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date);
```

By having an `Instant`, you can easily convert to whatever timezone you want (using the `ZoneId` class to convert it to a `ZonedDateTime`), and then using a `DateTimeFormatter` to change the format:

```
// convert Date to Instant, and then to a timezone
ZonedDateTime z = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
// format it
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formatted = fmt.format(z);
System.out.println(formatted); // 2017-10-11 17:22:30
```

---

To parse a `String` is similar. You use a `DateTimeFormatter`, then parse to a `LocalDateTime` (because the input `String` doesn't have a timezone in it), then you convert it to a timezone (and you can optionally convert it to a `Date` if you need):

```
String input = "09/10/2017 21:53:17";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
// parse the input
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, parser);
// convert to a timezone
ZonedDateTime z = dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
// you can format it, just as above

// you can also convert it to a Date
Date d = Date.from(z.toInstant());
```

If you want to convert to UTC, use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of the `ZoneId`. Also, [check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) for more details about the formats (they're not always the same used by `SimpleDateFormat`).

Comment: `timestamp` is quite ambiguous, with different meaning is various computing situations. I suggest calling a count of seconds/milliseconds etc from the epoch reference date a “count-from-epoch”.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer, especially the part about printing dates.